# Cannot open Emulator on freshly installed Android Studio - Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value

Tags: android

before people start pointing to this as a duplicate - I've went through a lot of different topics on this and I can not figure this out...

I've **AMD Ryzen processor**.

The error:

```
Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Android\sdk]! [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

SDK is fully installed:

[image]

Environment variables:

[image]

SDK installed:

[image]

Windows features:

[image]

VIRTUALIZATION is enabled on my BIOS. So, what am I missing here? Any ideas? SDK folder looks good (nothing is missing), location paths are correct, but error is still happening.

Android studio version is 3.5.3.